# Does wind turbulence increase or decrease with height from ground?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, turbulence

[image]

Above is a picture of laminar to turbulent transition on a flow past a plate. Towards the right edge, we see that the layer closer to the surface is more laminar than turbulent, while away from the surface there are much more turbulent eddies. The turbulence seems to increase with height from the surface.

Then let's look at wind flowing over ground. The picture below is from [this](https://newgreenbusinessideas.blogspot.com/search/label/Smart%20Siting?m=0) website.

[image]

Now here there is an obstruction on the flow path. This creates turbulence, which is now higher near the ground, and decreases with height. In my mind, having buildings etc. on ground is analogous to the plate in the first picture having surface friction due to roughness.

Another context where we assume the turbulence to decrease with height is in structural engineering. There the turbulence intensity $I$, which is defined as the ratio of the standard deviation of the instantaneous wind speed to average wind is inversely proportional to height $z$:

$$I \propto \frac{1}{log(\frac{z}{z_0})}$$

where $z_0$ is a constant. This formula is from Eurocode.

To me, these two scenarios seem quite the same, but the turbulence is the other way around. In the flow past the plate, turbulence increases with height. In flow past ground, turbulence decreases with height. A way I think about this is that the plate has friction, which can be thought of as similar obstacles to flow as the house in the second picture, just in microscale. Considering winds blow at very large height scales compared to objects on ground, I would think obstructions like built environment appears to wind as similar small scale friction as the friction of the plate for the flow past it.

**So why does the turbulence seem reversed in these two situations?**

Comment: Just an observation from lots of air travel experience. I have found that, typically, when approaching a landing turbulence diminishes the closer you get to the ground.